# Vuetify v-data-table calculations

Tags: vuetify.js, v-data-table

Is it possible to do calculations in v-data-table cells?

I created a basic example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/snovak/pen/LYdmBgv)

The basic idea would be something like this:

```
const headers = [
  { text: 'Dessert (100g serving)', value: 'name' },
  { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
  { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
  { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
  { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
  { text: 'Calculate something', value: calc('calories', 'fat') },
];

function calc(calories, fat){
  //do some kind of calculation with data from JSON
  return(calories * fat)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this using data table slots. The v-data-table provides a large number of slots for customizing the table.

```js
const headers = [
  { text: "Calories * Fat", value: "prod" }
]
```

```html
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" :items-per-page="4" class="elevation-1">
  <template v-slot:item.prod="{ item }">
    {{ item.calories * item.fat }}
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

We can also call the computed|methods function to do more complex calculations.

See ref: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#slots

See working CodePen here: https://codepen.io/kiran589/pen/rNdvrXZ